# HTML/Javascript: Detect when draggable element is NOT dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I am making an electron application that uses HTML drag and drop functionality to move tabs between windows. If a tab is dragged onto another tab in a tabpane it will move it there and if the tab is dragged anywhere else it will create a new window with the tab (Similar to how any modern web browser would).

However the drop event triggers in the window that has the tab dropped on it not the one the tab was dragged from, meaning I have no way of knowing if the tab was dropped on a tabpane or not when the user tries to drag a tab from one windows tabpane to another's. This means I cannot cancel the creation of a new window in the dragend event and the user cannot drag a tab to another window's tabpane.

```
var tabDropped = false;

$(document).on('drop', '.tabpane__tabs li', function(e) {
    // Tab was dropped on a tabpane, move it there
    tabDropped = true; // This does not work because it is called in a different window
});

$(document).on('dragend', function(e) {
    if (!tabDropped) {
        // Tab was not dropped on a tabpane, create a new window with the tab
    }
});
```

I have tried clearing the dataTransfer's data after the drop event, but dataTransfer is protected in the dragend event so I cannot detect if the data has been cleared or not. I believe sending an ipc message after a drop would be too slow and the dragend event would trigger before the window would receive the message. How can I detect if a drop has happened or not in the dragend event?

Comment: all the documents are from the same domain?

Comment: They are the same `let win = new BrowserWindow(...); win.loadURL(\`file://${__sourcedir}/win.html\`);`

Comment: Dont know about electron, but generally, `file://` protocol is never considered same-origin... That's unfortunate... But actually, since you hold references of these windows, can't you communicate with it afterward (either by directly attaching DOM events if allowed, or by using [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)?)

Comment: I can send an ipc message, but the dragend event will fire before the message is received.